# how to show a alert box in a delegate method (User defined) in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiapplicationdelegate, uialertviewdelegate

I have written a function named as register which connects with the server and calls register done method (if connection established successfully) which is a delegate method,now here i am trying to display alertbox but the UI gets stucked and the glow appears but the alert box doesnt?
Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show the alert from background thread you should not do that you need to show the alert from the main thread